# How to delete object from array in Amplify Datastore

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I manage to delete an object from the front end using this:

```
const deleteItem = async (index) => {
      let removeItem = [...storeItems];
      removeItem.splice(index, 1);
      setStoreItems(removeItem);
 };
```

Now i'm trying to delete the object from a list queried from amplify datastore and set to a state "storeItems" like this:

```
const deleteItem = async (index) => {
      let removeItem = [...storeItems];
      removeItem.splice(index, 1);
      setStoreItems(removeItem);
      const todelete = await DataStore.query(StoreItem, storeItems.id);
      DataStore.delete(todelete);
  };
```

And i keep getting this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Object is not an instance of a valid model]
```

The list is queried in a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch Comments
    const fetchStoreItem = async () => { 
      const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      const userSub = userInfo.attributes.sub;
      const user = (await DataStore.query(User)).find(u => u.sub === userSub);
        if (!storeItems) {
            return;
        }
        const storeItem = (await DataStore.query(StoreItem))
            .filter((StoreItem) => StoreItem.userID === user.id);
            setStoreItems(storeItem)
    };
    fetchStoreItem();
  }, [storeItems]);
```

How can i go about doing this?

Comment: Did u manage to get the right `todelete` item? Try to console.log its value.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Console.log 'storeItems.id' shows Undefined. And 'storeItems.StoreItem.id' shows an iteration error